# how to add custom gui for a windows form though dll refrence

Tags: c#, dll, windowsformsintegration

I want to make some sort of .DLL in C#, and want to reference it and add stuff like buttons, checkboxes, and more. I want it to do that while having its own custom properties like setting it round with number % stuff and more, but not sure what project to use in visual studios and not sure how to do it.

For example, in the toolbox rounded_button properties, all the default stuff and then the custom light_up_on_hover (true or false) light_up_color (color) rounded (number of how round the button is).

Answer (score -3):

Make a new project in C#, select class library as a template (will build as DLL), or, if you already have a project, you can go into project settings to change the build settings to class library.
Define classes, custom buttons, etc; build the project ->get the .dll and reference it in any project you might want to use it in the future.

Best of luck!